# Javascript Regex convert string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not familiar with Javascript Regex. Can anyone tell me how to convert strings like "Minus162Plus140" into "-162,140", or "Plus162Minus140" into "162,-140" by using match or replace? thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Why do you have text in this format?

Answer (score -1):

You can just use string replace:

```js
text = "Minus162Plus140";
text = text.replace("Minus", ",-");
text = text.replace("Plus", ",+");

console.log(text);
```

Or regex:

```js
text = "Minus162Plus140";
re = /Plus/;
text = text.replace(re, ',+');
re = /Minus/;
text = text.replace(re, ',-');

// Then to remove the initial comma:

re = /^,/;
text = text.replace(re, '');

console.log(text);
```

Comment: It will not work for `Plus162Minus140` though

Answer (score -1):

Building on the previous answer, you'll also need to handle other cases, like "Plus162Minus140":

```
text = "Minus162Plus140";
text = text.replace(/^Minus/, "-");   // Handle when Minus comes first
text = text.replace("Minus", ",-");   // And second
text = text.replace(/^Plus/, "");     // Handle when Plus comes first
text = text.replace(/Plus/, ",");     // And second
```

But this approach itself is brittle, and assumes that the string will always be of the form `/^(Minus|Plus)\d+(Minus|Plus)\d+$/`, which you could validate first with a regular expression:

```
if (/^(Minus|Plus)\d+(Minus|Plus)\d+$/) {
  ... do the replacement
} else {
  ... handle the error
}
```